# How to convert a non-persistent docker container to persistent storage (volume)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### The problem

I messed up really badly, started a prestashop docker container (via compose) for production and forgot to add a persistent volume to it. I've set up my store and now all my data is dangling. I need to somehow convert my current docker container to one with persistent volume.

### Things I've tried

I've copied all data from current container to a local folder, created a new compose file and everything would work if I `chmod -R 777` whole directory but people go to hell for these types of crimes, so that's not an option.

**As I'm not an expert, I have no other ideas.**

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is most probably related to the user id / group id that is owning the files from the old container. When you move to the new container, if the IDs are not same you will have problem, so `chmod -R 777` is fixing this problem, but the gates of hell are wide open.

It's better to understand which user id and group id should be the owners of the files and use `chown` and `chgrp` to set the right owners from the new container.

Comment: Allright, I'll give this a try. I thought that there'd be a simpler docker-native way of doing this kind of conversion.

Comment: You are doing it in the most simples way. You can do it by hacking the container definition, I had done this several times, but this one has much wider gate to hell, don't go there

Answer (score 1):

Alright,

So it was a pretty simple solution:

1. `sudo su`
2. go to the non-persistent container storage location which you can get by using `docker inspect container` take the long string hash `822adf62adsomethingsomething`.
3. then `cd /var/lib/docker/overlay2/822adf62adsomethingsomething/merged`. There you have all your docker container files.
4. `cp -a whateveryouwant /whereeveryouwant` as `cp -a` keeps permissions and owners intact.
5. profit